# Use a common table with many to many relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two SQL tables: Job and Employee. I need to compare Job Languages Proficiencies and Employee Languages Proficiencies. A Language Proficiency is composed by a Language and a Language Level.

```
create table dbo.EmployeeLanguageProficiency (
  EmployeeId int not null, 
  LanguageProficiencyId int not null,
    constraint PK_ELP primary key clustered (EmployeeId, LanguageProficiencyId)
)

create table dbo.JobLanguageProficiency (
  JobId int not null, 
  LanguageProficiencyId int not null,
    constraint PK_JLP primary key clustered (JobId, LanguageProficiencyId)
)

create table dbo.LanguageProficiency (
  Id int identity not null
    constraint PK_LanguageProficiency_Id primary key clustered (Id),
  LanguageCode nvarchar (4) not null,
  LanguageLevelId int not null,
    constraint UQ_LP unique (LanguageCode, LanguageLevelId)
)

create table dbo.LanguageLevel ( 
  Id int identity not null
    constraint PK_LanguageLevel_Id primary key clustered (Id),
  Name nvarchar (80) not null
    constraint UQ_LanguageLevel_Name unique (Name)
)

create table dbo.[Language]
( 
  Code nvarchar (4) not null
    constraint PK_Language_Code primary key clustered (Code),
  Name nvarchar (80) not null
)
```

My question is about LanguageProficiency table. I added an Id has PK but I am not sure this is the best option.

What do you think about this scheme?

Comment: It looks ok. Add foreign keys. May be LanguageProficiency table is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Your constraint of EmployeeId, LanguageProficiencyId allows an employee to have more than one proficiency per language. This sounds counterintuitive.

This would be cleaner, as it allows only one entry per language:

```
create table dbo.EmployeeLanguageProficiency (
  EmployeeId int not null, 
  LanguageId int not null,
  LanguageLevelId int not null,
    constraint PK_ELP primary key clustered (EmployeeId, LanguageId)
)
```

I don't see the point of table LanguageProficiency at the moment.

Same applies to the Job of course. Unless you would like to allow a "range" of proficiencies. But assuming that "too high proficiency" does not hurt, it can easilly be defined through a >= statement in our queries.

Rgds